# Is there a way to synchronize ROS time and the time originating from a rosbag?

Tags: gazebo, navigation, simulation, odometry, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some details: I'd like to compare real world data with simulated data, for this reason I'd like to play a rosbag (containing the real world data) and apply the recorded commands to a Gazebo model of the robot. For this purpose I set /use_sim_time to true and call rosbag play with the option --clock. Unfortunately I observe jumps in /clock topic - as it seems to me both the simulated time (from Gazebo) and the time originating from the rosbag are published to /clock. This leads in the end to a defective result - in particular the odometry data provided by the robot_localization package comes along with huge variances (magnitude 1e+4).
Is there a solution to this problem? I would appreciate your help.

BR, Florian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396661/is-there-a-way-to-synchronize-ros-time-and-the-time-originating-from-a-rosbag?/) by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You likely recorded your bag with `-a`. You need to get the `/clock` topic out of it: `rosbag filter your_bag.bag clock_removed.bag "topic != /clock"`

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2022-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on 2022-02-25**:
Thank you Tom. This worked for me. =)

BR, Florian

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-02-25**:
@florian  Please don't create "an answer" that is not actually an answer to the question. To thank someone who helped you, you should use the link "add a comment" under their response.

**Comment by [rcbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/80739/rcbot/) on 2023-02-20**:
I found small syntax error in Tom's rosbag command. the topic name should be in single quote (for example: "topic != '/clock' ")
rosbag filter your_bag.bag clock_removed.bag "topic != '/clock' "